# Why does one can here not apply the optional sampling theorem?(Brownian motion, first time hitting one)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a standard brownian motion  and let $T=\inf\{t\ge 0 \mid B_t\ge 1\}$.
Now we have $E(B_0)=0$, but $ E(B_T)=1$, i.e. the optional sampling theorem can't be applied. The only issue could be that $T$ is not bounded, but actually it is, since $P(T<\infty)=1$ or where is the error?
Any comments/help on this are welcome!

> Theorem: Let $X$ adapted and right countinuous. Then $X$ is a martingale iff $E(X_T)=E(X_0)$ for all bounded stopping times $T$.

Comment: Bounded $T$ means $\mathsf{P}(T\le M)=1$ for some $M<\infty$.

Comment: There is a huge difference between $P(T<\infty)=1$ and $T$ bounded. The latter means there exist $M \in (0,\infty)$ such that $P(T\leq M)=1$.

Comment: thanks to both of you. Indeed I misunderstood this.